# How to perform a entity framwork group by

Tags: entity-framework-6

I have an entity framwork query, is this okay, or there are a better ways? It takes a log time to execute...

```
from orderRow in dboc.Order
join workerRow in dboc.Worker on orderRow.OperatorId equals workerRow.Id
where orderRow.AcceptedTime >= queryData.BeginAcceptedTime && workerRow.WorkerKindId == (int)WorkerKind.Human
group new { orderRow, workerRow } by orderRow.OperatorId
into grp
select new OperatorCompetitionInfo
{
    WorkerId = grp.Key,
    FullName = grp.FirstOrDefault().workerRow.FullNameWithCode,
    OrderCount = grp.Count()
}).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EF generates inefficient queries when you use non aggregate functions like `FirstOrDefault` on the result of the `group by` operator.

If the value is expected to be one and the same inside the grouping, you'd better use `Min` or `Max` method instead (for equal values, `Min`, `Max` and `First` should return one and the same result), which will be translated to much better SQL query.

So, try replacing

```
FullName = grp.FirstOrDefault().workerRow.FullNameWithCode,
```

with

```
FullName = grp.Min(item => item.workerRow.FullNameWithCode),
```

and see if that helps.

Comment: thank you Ivan, so is better, thank you one more time